# What's the best most CPU efficient way to draw views with a lot of animations in iOS?

Tags: ios, ios6

I'm trying to draw a graphic equaliser for an iOS project.

The equaliser will have 7 bars, representing different frequency bands, than move up and down based on real-time audio data.

Can anyone suggest the best way to approach this in iOS?

New frequency data comes in at about 11Hz, and so the bars would have to animate to a new size 11 times per second.

1. Do I create a UIView for each bar and dynamically resize it's frame height?
2. Do I draw the bars as thick CGStrokes and redraw them within the parent view as needed?
3. Another option?

Thanks in advance

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SpeakHere/Listings/AudioViews_LevelMeter_m.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007802-AudioViews_LevelMeter_m-DontLinkElementID_8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to use Core Animation. The basic principle is to create a bunch of "layer" objects, which can either be bitmap images, vector shapes, or text. Each layer is stored on the GPU and most operations can be animated at 60 frames per second.

Think of layers like a DOM node in a HTML page, they can be nested inside each other and you can apply attributes to each one similar to CSS. The list of attributes available matches everything the GPU can do efficiently.

It sounds like you want vector shapes. Basically you create all your shapes at startup, for example in the `awakeFromNib` method of a `UIView` subclass. For simple rectangles use `CALayer` and set a background colour. For more complicated shapes create a `CAShapeLayer` and a `UIBezierPath`, then apply it with `shapeLayer.path = bezierPath.CGPath;`.

Then, whenever you want to change something, you apply those changes to the layer object. For example, here I'm rotating a layer with a 1 second linear animation:

```
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setAnimationDuration:1];
[CATransaction setAnimationTimingFunction:[CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionLinear]];

[self.needleLayer setValue:[NSNumber numberWithFloat:DegreesToRadians(degrees) forKeyPath:@"transform.rotation.z"];

[CATransaction commit];


// you'll want to declare this somewhere  
CGFloat DegreesToRadians(CGFloat degrees)
{
  return degrees * M_PI / 180;
}
```

More complicated animations, eg a series of changes scheduled to execute back to back, can be done using a `CAKeyframeAnimation`: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreAnimation_guide/CreatingBasicAnimations/CreatingBasicAnimations.html

Note Core Animation only does 2D graphics. Apple has Scene Kit which is basically the same thing for 3D, but so far it's only available on OS X. Hopefully iOS 8 will include it, but until then if you want 3D graphics on iOS you need to use Open GL.

Answer (score 1):

CALayers which you resize on demand would probably be the most efficient way to do this, if the bars are solid colours. This allows you to optionally animate between sizes as well.

View resizing triggers off layout cycles, which you don't want. Drawing using CG calls is pretty slow.

Obviously the only real way to find out is to profile (on a device) using instruments and the core animation tool. But from experience, layer sizing is faster than drawing.

Answer (score -1):

Definitely not a UIView for each - instead, a single UIView for the entire equalizer. Fill in the drawRect method with the appropriate CG calls to draw whatever is required. You can queue the view to refresh as needed with the appropriate data. Tapping into CADisplayLink will help you get the frame-rate you're looking for.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/QuartzCore/Reference/CADisplayLink_ClassRef/Reference/Reference.html

NOTE: You can also subclass CALayer and draw in it if you prefer something lighter-weight than UIView but I think you'll be fine with the former.

Comment: Don't use drawRect if you want performance. It has to be executed 60 times per second, which simply isn't fast enough except for extremely basic drawing.

Comment: His original request was for 11 times a second - drawRect should be fine for that if he wants a UIView subclass.

Comment: They need to update 11 times per second, but they need 60 frames per second of animation in between updates. So you'll still need drawRect to execute faster than 1/60th of a second. In general, drawRect should be avoided in modern obj-c programming. It made sense for Display Postscript on slow hardware but does have acceptable performance today, even on fast hardware like a Mac Pro. - http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_PostScript

Comment: If the underlying data is updating 11 times per second there is no reason to draw changes 60 times (or more) per second. You're basically wasting cycles drawing the exact same data. Obviously you can optimize by returning immediately from the call but the bottom line is the granularity of the data updates will drive what the user will see anyway on the UI side. Am I missing something?

Comment: Yeah, you're missing the part where any change to the user interface (eg: an object changing size) should be animated at 60fps. With drawRect you have to draw all 60 frames from scratch each time, with CALayer only the part that changed needs to be drawn and it will be done on the GPU instead of the CPU. Also, even if you don't have any animation, the performance improvement for using CALayer instead of drawRect is significant enough to impact battery life.